# Como fazer para usar um banco de dados já existente em uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC C# e Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net, asp.net-identity

Preciso fazer autenticação de usuários.

Então criei meu banco de dados com todas as minhas regras de negócio, fiz a conexão com a aplicação ASP.NET MVC, e comecei a programar.

Agora, quando fui fazer a parte de *login* de usuário percebi que o existem duas conexões, uma chamada `DefaultConnection` e a minha do `SQLServer`.

A pergunta é: como mudar o ASP.NET Identity para eu poder usar somente a conexão do meu banco de dados local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Das duas uma:

- Ou refazes a parte de login a aceder às tuas tabelas da tua base de dados.
- Ou então adicionas o ASP.NET Identity como uma base de dados auxiliar na mesma instância de SQL que acede à tua base de dados.

A primeira opção parece complicada mas não é, e permite-te um controlo total sobre os teus Logins e Roles.

Eu optei pela segunda porque já tinha o projecto praticamente feito já a mexer no Identity.

Comment: Eu não entendi como funcionaria essa primeira opção.

Comment: Tens que estudar os Controllers da parte onde é usado o Identity e ir buscar a mesma informação à tua base de dados.

Por exemplo os Controllers de Login ou Register, em vez de ir buscar o utilizador e a password ao Identity tem que ir buscar à tua BD.

Comment: Obrigado! Acho que entendi como se faz. Utilizei o model do Identity como um ViewModel e no meu Controller recebi do modelo e salvei no meu banco de dados.